# Swing MenuEvent menuCanceled

Tags: java, swing

I don't understand when `menuCanceled` is invoked on a `JMenu`.

In fact when I open a menu is called `menuSelected` when I close a menu is called
`menuDeselected` but never will be called `menuCanceled`.

Any examples?

Answer (score 2):

You are right that `MenuListener#menuCanceled` is called from `JMenu#fireMenuCanceled` but the latter doesn't seem to be called anywhere from Windows JDK6.

It could be there for historical reasons or some other platform LAFs, and you have to implement it anyway, so just call `menuDeselected` from it.